# Monotonic "Subfunction"

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $f$: $\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary function.

Must there exist $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ of size continuum, such that $f$ restricted to $E$ is monotonic?

I guess this question can be generalized to functions $\kappa\longrightarrow\kappa$, with $\kappa$ infinite.

Comment: With/without AoC?

Comment: Both cases are interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no. This follows from the following.

Claim (Sierpinski, Zygmund): There exists a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, if $A$ has size continuum, then $f \upharpoonright A$ is not Borel.

Proof sketch: Construct $f$ such that for every real valued function $g$ with $dom(g)$ uncountable Borel, $\{x \in dom(g) : f(x) = g(x)\}$ has size less than continuum.

Comment: Perfect, just perfect. I thought it'd be too good to be true. And the construction works without CH or $\neg$CH?

Comment: Yes, since there are only continuum many requirements $g$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If $A$ has size continuum and is not Borel, why does this prevent $f\upharpoonright A$ to be monotone?

Comment: Since then $f$ would agree with one of the $g$'s on a set of size continuum.

Comment: Please excuse my slowness today. I suppose the idea is that if $ A $ is a set of reals and $ f:A\to\mathbb R $ is monotone, then $ f $ can be extended to a monotone function with domain $\bar A $ (and this is clear). Very nice.

Comment: Do you see how to proceed in the absence of choice?

Comment: I think I can show that if $f$ is measurable/has Baire property, then it is monotone on a perfect set so a counter example must use some choice.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're thinking about a situation with dependent choice, though. :-)

Comment: @hot_queen Could you or someone else recommend a reference for this kind of material? This is the closest that I found, but it doesn't seem to cover the above result: http://www.math.wvu.edu/~kcies/Other/ElectronicReprints/56.pdf

Comment: @Mathgemini You can find a proof on page 165 of this book: A. B. Kharazishvili, Strange functions in real analysis, 2nd Ed.

Comment: Strange functions indeed. Thanks

Comment: What happens (under $\neg$CH) if in the original question we replace continuum by $\aleph_1$?

Comment: I think this is independent of ZFC. If you post this as a separate question, I will try to think of the details and post it.